# Angular-strap $affix service instantiation issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm trying to use Angular-strap's $affix service to programmatically attach affix behavior to 3 different elements; two of these must respond to whether the target browser is roughly desktop-width or greater (in which case they MUST NOT affix), and the third must always affix.  A complicating factor is whether or not the receiving device is either a desktop browser or a mobile device (& further whether said mobile device is either in landscape or portrait mode), because there are stylistic adjustments required for various device breakpoints, and this drives changes to the affix offsets for these three elements.

To this end I've managed to put together some logic for handling these different cases, and to keep sane I've located the logic for my use of $affix within its own directive attached to my Angular app.  I've also isolated logic for detecting orientationchange events in its own directive, and within my affix directive I've got a callback setup to trip on orient::change, which calls my handleFixes() function, which in turn calls my helper functions (to recalculate the proper offsets) and then calls $affix() on each affixed element to update its behavior.

In theory this should work fine.  In practice it looks like the $affix service is unable to attach callbacks to "scroll", "click" or "resize" events, because it's expecting targetEl to be an element but instead it's undefined.  As a result, $affix isn't working at all.

I *think* what's happening is my directive definition isn't properly communicating the intended target element (the BODY tag) into $affix, but that may not be the end of it.

Here's my directive definition **EDITED**:

```
// N.B. Deliberate mis-spelling of "affix" below
searchFilter.directive('aptAfix', function($affix, $window) {

    var afixDirectiveObject = {

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // Helpers:
            var onDesktop = function () {
                    var win = $(window),
                        windowWidth = win.width(),
                        minDesktopWidth = 959;
                    return (windowWidth > minDesktopWidth);
                },

                getDevClass = function () {
                    var win = $(window),
                        winWidth = win.width(),
                        minDesktopWidth = 959;

                    if (winWidth > minDesktopWidth) {
                        return "desktop";
                    } else {
                        return "device";
                    }
                },

                // Affix-specific logic
                getFirstNavOffset = function () {
                    /* This nav hides at narrower breakpoints; so we need to know if it's visible; if so, we just return its current offset; if not, we determine its current offset relative to the secondary nav */

                    var visible = $('.primary-nav-wrap').is(':visible'),
                        second, secondOff, out;

                    if (getDevClass() === "desktop") {
                        out = 100000;
                    } else {
                        second = $('.secondary-nav-wrap');
                        secondOff = second.offset();
                        if (secondOff && secondOff.top) {
                            out = secondOff.top + (visible ? 40 : 10);
                        } else {
                            out = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    // Transform answer into string; used to prevent $affix from trying to call .match() on a numeric offset (causing borkage):
                    return out+"";
                },

                getSecondNavOffset = function () {
                    var second, secondOff, out;

                    if (getDevClass() === "desktop") {
                        out = 100000;
                    } else {
                        second = $('.secondary-nav-wrap');
                        secondOff = second.offset();
                        if (secondOff && secondOff.top) {
                            out = secondOff.top + 10;
                        } else {
                            out = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return out+"";
                },

                getLockbarOffset = function () {
                    var lock = $('#lockbar'),
                        lockOff = lock.offset(),
                        out;

                    if (lockOff && lockOff.top) {
                        out = lockOff.top + (onDesktop() ? 60 : 30);
                    } else {
                        out = 0;
                    }
                    return out+"";
                },

                // Our utility function for running everything; will run
                // @ start & on orient::change events
                handleFixes = function () {
                    var win = angular.element($window),
                        e1 = angular.element('.primary-nav-wrap'),
                        e2 = angular.element('.secondary-nav-wrap'),
                        e3 = angular.element('#lockbar'),

                        e1Data = { offsetTop: getFirstNavOffset(), target: win },
                        e2Data = { offsetTop: getSecondNavOffset(), target: win },
                        e3Data = { offsetTop: getLockbarOffset(), target: win };

                    // EVERYTHING WORKS GREAT *UP TO THIS POINT*
                    // NOW WE MUST $affix() ELEMENTS!

                    $affix(e1, e1Data);
                    $affix(e2, e2Data);
                    $affix(e3, e3Data);
                };

            /* If you get "orient::change", update fixatives' offsets */
            scope.$on('orient::change', function() {
                handleFixes();
            });

            /* Trip our call to activate  */
            handleFixes();
        }
    };

    return afixDirectiveObject;
});
```

FTR, I'm running this code with Angular 1.2.23 & Angular-strap 2.1.0.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or insight.

Comment: OK, I've figured out that I need to grab the BODY tag and attach it as a "target" property on the options objects I'm using to call $affix; that has at least solved the errors, but the $affix calls aren't having the intended effect -- namely the elements I want to affix to the BODY are not in fact exhibiting affix behavior when I scroll the page.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, I went about it the wrong way.  Initially I figured out that the reason I didn't seem to have a target element was that I wasn't explicitly passing a "target" option into $affix().  On the assumption that it was an appropriate target I tried using $('body').

When it became apparent that this still wasn't having the intended effect -- that is, nothing I wanted to affix to the page was actually affixing to the page, despite the absence of any errors in the console log -- I decided to figure out how bs-affix works, found its definition in the source code and voila!  Clear as day, it attempts to resolve a provided target element, but lacking that it resolves to "angular.element($window)".  Obviously I didn't have $window readily available in my directive, so after adding it alongside the $affix service in my injected parameters, I used it instead of "$('body')" and things are now working as intended.

I hope this is helpful for anyone else who's looking to use the $affix service for any non-trivial element affixing with Angular-strap.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 more times.  Thank you!